# Laravel images path doesn't work properly

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

can somebody help me with my issue?
I created an app with laravel 5.3(i didn't have experience with laravel before) so it works just ok on my local apache, but when i uploaded it on shared hosting, i have been faced with a problem with an images path.
My images uploaded with voyager admin panel and they are stored in MySite\storage\app\public\products\January2017
Here is my method to get records from table, everything works ok besides images path

```
  public function search(Request $req) {

    $q = $req->input('search');

    $error = ['error'=>'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено'];
    if($req->has('q')) {
        //$product = json_decode(Product::search($req->get('q'))->get(), true);
        $res = Product::search($req->get('q'))->first();
        // dd($res->toArray());
        return view('pages.found', [
            'data' => $res->toArray()
        ]);
    }
    else {
        $product = Product::all();
        return view('pages.welcome')->withPosts($product);
    }
}
```

and this is how i show it.

images uploads in db with a path products/February2017/Xq6nkdTRAWcgKg07LsI4.png for example

it works on my local server where composer installed, on this hosting i can't install it to, so what should i do to make it work?

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: can you provide the code in `pages/welcome` view?

Comment: Try to add the images to `/public/` folder in the root of your laravel installation

Answer (score 0):

The `storage` folder is not accessible to the public (since it's outside the `public` folder), and it should stay as such.

The only way you can achieve what you want, while keeping the files where they are at the moment, is to symlink your `storage/app/public/product` folder to `public/product`.

On Mac / *nix, this would work: `ln -s /full/path/to/laravel/storage/app/public/products /full/path/to/laravel/public/products`.

Answer (score 0):

you use

php artisan storage:link

By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public.

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

That creates a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` for you and that's all there is to it. Now any file in `/storage/app/public` can be accessed via a link like:

```
http://somedomain.com/storage/image.jpg
```